# How to benchmark a Pallet public functions?

Tags: weight

I watched polkadot seminar on benchmarking here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qa6sTyUqgek&t=9177s

Can any one please guid how to benchmark a pallet public functions? more ever, it will be nice if there is some example with step wise explanation

Answer (score 0):

Check this [How-To-guide](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/weights/add-benchmarks/) that explains how to write a simple benchmark for a pallet.

If you want to see an easy code example, you can check the Pallet template in the Substrate Node Template that is a simply pallet for example that has a function [do_something](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L69) and [here you can see the code where is adding the benchmarking for that function.](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/src/benchmarking.rs)

If you want more complex examples, check [the code of the FRAME pallets](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame) that are pallets provided by Substrate.

More information about Benchmarking: [In the Substrate Docs](https://docs.substrate.io/test/benchmark/) and the [Substrate Runtime Benchmarking Framework](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/benchmarking/README.md).

Comment: What is the difference between the macros in the how-to guide `benchmarks! { .. }` and the `#[benchmark]` in the pallet-template? Are they similar in functionality?

Comment: The benchmarks! {} is the new benchmarking macro syntax. Check this PR: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12924